# How to avoid a memory leak in this code?

Tags: c, memory-leaks, c++-cli

I've the next code, at the click event of a button:

```
         PNIO_DEV_ADDR addr;
         addr.AddrType = PNIO_ADDR_GEO;     //Para IO Device
         addr.IODataType = PNIO_IO_OUT;     //Escritura en PLC
         addr.u.Geo.Slot = (int)(numericUpDownSlot->Value);
         addr.u.Geo.Subslot = (int)(numericUpDownSubslot->Value);

         CP1626::write(&addr);
```

`PNIO_DEV_ADDR` is a C struct, and `write` is a function linked to a DLL callback, which asks for a `PNIO_DEV_ADDR*` parameter.

Each time I press the button I can see at the task manager how the memory associated to my app increases a few bytes.

I've googled and read a lot about pointers and references but I don't quite understand what I'm doing wrong.

Could you explain me where is the problem, please?

P.S.: I'm using a C library (built on a DLL) and a C++/CLI application.

Thank you in advance.

EDIT:

`PNIO_DEV_ADDR` is:

```
typedef struct {
    PNIO_ADDR_TYPE  AddrType;
    PNIO_IO_TYPE    IODataType;
    union {
        PNIO_UINT32 Addr;
        struct {
            PNIO_UINT32 reserved1[2];
            PNIO_UINT32 Slot;
            PNIO_UINT32 Subslot;
            PNIO_UINT32 reserved2;
        } Geo;                   /* geographical address */
    } u;
} ATTR_PACKED PNIO_DEV_ADDR;
```

When the two first variables are enums.

EDIT2:

This is the entry point of the function `write` inside the DLL:

```
PNIO_UINT32 write(PNIO_DEV_ADDR* addr){
    PNIO_UINT32 result;

    result = PNIOD_trigger_data_write_sync(g_devHndl, addr, PNIO_ACCESS_RT_WITH_LOCK);

    return result;
}
```

`PNIO_trigger_data_write_sync` requires a `PNIO_DEV_ADDR*`. Sorry but I can't access inside this function because it is on a different DLL which is third party. Should I've copied the `addr` pointer?

Comment: Where is the allocation taking place? If `addr` is really a struct and not some pointer type, and you have a function `write(PNIO_DEV_ADDR*)`, then no allocation takes place/should take place anywhere. It is of course possible that `write` leaks memory internally.

Comment: @Lundin I've edited my question and added the struct

Comment: try to use _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks()

Comment: Nobody will be able to reproduce the problem with what's given here. Windows task manager isn't all that reliable. Are you sure there's a memory leak?

Comment: @Lundin yes, memory is not oscillating as there is in other applications. But at the moment I click the button it increases a few bytes, and never goes back to the initial value.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/413477/is-there-a-good-valgrind-substitute-for-windows

Comment: Task Manager has many memory fields it can show (most of which aren't particularly informative about small memory leaks).  Which field are you looking at?

Comment: Field 'Memory', on 'Process' tab (Windows 10 task manager)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two kinds of memory allocation in `C/C++`, one is memory allocation during compile time and other one is `dynamic memory`(memory allocation during run time) allocation and I am sure you know about this. memory allocation during compile is done form `stack` of an application and `dynamic` memory allocation is done from `heap` of an application. We need to concern about memory release which is allocated (dynamically) from `heap` to avoid memory leak. For memory release from stack `compiler` automatically manage it.

In your case the allocation is done from `stack`. Hence once the control go out of the scope of the method where your current codes are, it will automatically release the memory of stack.

Now in your case `PNIO_DEV_ADDR addr;`, this is compile time memory allocation and is not dynamically allocated memory at all. So it will not leads to memory leak.

Inside the `dll` method, I am sure it has copied your object to its local object.

Comment: `static` storage duration variables have nothing to do with the stack at all. Fixed-size arrays are sometimes sloppily called "static", since the size is set at compile time. Perhaps this is what you mean.

Comment: I have modified my answer. But don't understood why you have downvoted.

Comment: I haven't. Although I'm not sure how this answers the question. In fact I don't think it is possible to answer the question, as it stands.

Comment: if you see his question he is asking how he can avid the memory leak in this case:- PNIO_DEV_ADDR addr; (but this is compile time memory allocation) . This is not dynamically allocated memory. So it will not leads to memory leak.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @AbhijitPritam. Maybe the problem is inside the DLL. It's not mine but I have the source code, so I'm posting the entry point on my question. Just give me a minute, please. And again, thank you for your answer.

Comment: @AbhijitPritam sure! Sadly it seems that recently is easier to get a negative vote than to get a positive one...

Comment: @AbhijitPritam `PNIO_DEV_ADDR addr;` looks like a local variable. It is not "compile time memory allocation", it is run-time automatic allocation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_variable